# Converting function from Code Fluent to Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, codefluent

I'm working in a project with Code Fluent but we need to migrate it to Entity Framework 
So I need help to convert this function or finding its equivalent maybe

---

```
 public static System.Data.DataSet GetSpaces(System.Guid userId)
    {
        if ((userId.Equals(CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue) == true))
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("userId");
        }
        System.Data.DataSet ret = default(System.Data.DataSet);
        CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence persistence = CodeFluentContext.Get(Erpeo.Store.Model.Constants.Erpeo_Store_ModelStoreName).Persistence;
        persistence.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(null, "User", "GetSpaces");
        persistence.AddParameter("@userId", userId);
        System.Data.IDataReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            reader = persistence.ExecuteReader();
            if ((reader.Read() == true))
            {
                ret = CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence.LoadDataSet(reader);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((reader != null))
            {
                reader.Dispose();
            }
            persistence.CompleteCommand();
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you already have created the DbContext, Models and Migrations. If not, I recommend to read through the Entity Framework Core MS docs (I am assuming you are on dot net core)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) is the page you can begin with.

You have to create the DbContext derivation which will include all your DbSet (data models/DB entities). I am assuming it be looking as below, if you already have,

```
public class User
{
    //Your User table columns named properties
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Integrated Security=True");
    }
}
```

Here's the EF equivalent of your code mentioned above,

```
public static User[] GetSpaces(System.Guid userId)
{
    if (userId.Equals(Guid.Empty))
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("userId");
    }
    var ret = default(User[]);
    try
    {
        using (var persistence = new MyDbContext())
        {
            ret = persistence.Users.FromSql("GetSpaces", userId).ToArrayAsync().Result;
        }
    }
    catch { }
    finally { }
    return ret;
}
```

You will really have to provide much details to make this solution matching your requirement, but this is much of how it would translate to what your ask is.

Comment: sry for the delay but it is a dot net mvc application and so i can't use fromSql

Comment: And the return type is System.Data.DataSet and not User[]